# Nanoscale hydrogen batteries that use water-splitting technology

Tags: water, energy, hydrogen

It was [claimed in this article](https://www.ll.mit.edu/news/smaller-faster-better-nanoscale-batteries-may-power-future-technology) in 2019 that a nano-battery using water splitting technology is developed. It is described as:

> The battery gains its charge by interacting with water molecules present in the surrounding air. When a water molecule comes in contact with the reactive, outer metal section of the battery, it is split into its constituent parts — one molecule of oxygen and two of hydrogen. The hydrogen molecules become trapped inside the battery and can be stored until they are ready to be used. In this state, the battery is "charged." To release the charge, the reaction reverses. The hydrogen molecules move back through the reactive metal section of the battery and combine with oxygen in the surrounding air.

There are hardy any details on the article regarding the mechanism of this reaction and I wonder what the material of “the reactive, outer metal section” is. And I have found no paper published with this research. The description makes this battery sounds like a perpetual machine: splitting waters from environment into oxygen and hydrogen, and make hydrogen and oxygen react to create electricity. What would be a good explanation of the mechanisms that makes this possible?  I guess there must be other things going on to keep this described mechanism going, which limits the life of this battery.

It is also claimed that:

> The batteries have also demonstrated a power density that is two orders of magnitude greater than most currently used batteries.

But no experimental data is provided (since there’s no paper found).

Also no application of this battery has been recorded. I wonder **what is the water-splitting mechanism? And what is the proper material applied in the reactive metal section of this battery to split the water molecule?** If it is really this amazing I believe it can be applied inside human bodies to split water and power devices as well, since both nanoscale and larger scale such batteries can be made. But is such technology really practical and applicable now?

Comment: You will have look up their original research articles. The essays in your link are written by journalists where the main interest is to create curiousity or present a higly simplied version to public about something complicated. No wonder there is *no* scientific insight or content there.

Comment: @MFarooq Yes and that’s exactly what I did. But as I stated in the question, I found no paper related to this claimed result at all. That why I am asking the question.

Comment: I just saw the last lines "The Laboratory team's project will be the first to apply the technique for creating batteries, and at much smaller scales.

The project was funded via the Laboratory's Technology Office Energy Initiative and has entered into phase two of development, which includes optimizing the batteries further and integrating them with sensors."

Comment: So this is all imaginary so far. Nothing concrete. They will work on this idea.

Comment: Maybe... but it also says “ The batteries have also demonstrated a power density that is two orders of magnitude greater than most currently used batteries.” Sound like they’ve built a prototype already.

Comment: Looks and smells like one of those ‘all hat and no cattle’ things. Could be a tight race between these cells and commercial fusion power.